# 2012 Dodge Grand Caravan clutch/transmission fail

Tags: automatic-transmission, dodge, grand-caravan

car has 110,000 miles on the clock so out of warranty and today it won't drive. Car will shift into drive or reverse make a slight grinding noise and move a short distance then judder and stop. Engine runs fine.

I got an engine light a couple of days ago and checked it at autozone which gave code P0740 torque converter clutch solenoid circuit/ open?

Will This be a new transmission, clutch or other?